# About branch author

Tags: git, gitlab

I would like to know which **GIT** command I should use to know **WHO** actually created **BRANCH**.

I already looked in several posts here, but I always find the solution of the author of the last branch commit and not who actually created it.

I AM USING GITLAB

Comment: Are you using github? It should be easy to find there.

Comment: @MaxFerreira Did you see in gitlab-->repository-->graph ? it maybe help you up.

Comment: Can I ask why you need that? Maybe It's just an XY problem...

Answer (score 3):

Branches are only a pointer to a commit in git.  Who created the branch doesn't exist at all.  So there isn't a command to find out who created a branch.

In order to find out who created a branch, you would likely need to tap into the Gitlab api and watch the push events that happen.  When you see a branch for the first time, the user would be the person that created the new branch.

Comment: git is so phenomenal and such a simple thing, it does not have an easy way to see that information

Comment: Branches not containing this information is part of what makes Git so phenomenal.  They are so lightweight and easy to create allowing parallel development easily, adding this information opens the door to them becoming more weighty

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this help you up:

```
git log --graph --decorate
```

Or:

```
git log --graph --decorate |grep Author
```

Comment: The graph can also be seen in `Gitlab`. But creator of the branch cannot be known by graph because, one can create a branch and didn't have to do anything. Another person may do operations on it.

Comment: @RajanaDeepak yes you're right, I said also 'check graph in GitLab' in question's comment. I posted this answer because I thought maybe useful to find first author commit on an specific branch.